# Github client for mac: how to overcome the Great Wall?

Tags: git, github-for-mac

I had bought the VPN to through the GreatWall. I just want to know how to set up the proxy for the GitHub client for OS X.

In shell, it's like this.

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '[192.30.252.149]:443' to the list of known hosts.
Hi XXXXXX! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But when I click the button <kbd>Clone in Desktop</kbd>, it can't clone in the client.

For example: AFNetworking

> "Can't find "AFNetworking/AFNetworking", "It was last seen at ~/Github/AFNetworking".

---

Just now I verify it, the shell is kidding me.

The result that clone in the shell is like this.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
Cloning into 'AFNetworking'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that GFW only block contents distributed with CDN of github, like `assets-cdn.github.com`. Repo operations with git will almost not be affected by GFW.

And if you are connected to a VPN, you already penetrate GFW. You issue is probably not caused by network.

You can try to `git clone https://github.com/afnetworking/afnetworking`, then drag the local repo to **Github Mac**